# How to add a searchbar to tableview in swift?

Tags: swift, firebase, uitableview, uisearchbar

I am trying to add in a search bar function to actually filter my data. I have been able to generate the data that I need and populate it into a tableview. However, when I go to search using the following code, the searching variable always comes back as false so the tableview never gets updated.

Comment: Is the delegate set? By the way, your `didSelect` method will likely crash eventually.

Comment: `searchBar:textDidChange:` is a delegate method which gets called when the user presses a key. You have to tell the object where the method is implemented. The answers describe how to set the delegate. And the code can crash because `didSelectRowAt` gets always the selected item from the filtered array, even when the user is currently not searching.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class MainTableViewController: UITableViewController {
    
    let searchBarController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
    let listData = ["Sam", "Jam", "Tam", "Pam", "Kam", "Nam", "Mam"]
    var filteredData = [String]()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        title = "Demo"
        setSearchBarUI()
        getFilteredData()
    }
    
    func setSearchBarUI() {
        searchBarController.searchBar.delegate = self
        searchBarController.obscuresBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
        searchBarController.searchBar.sizeToFit()
        navigationItem.searchController = searchBarController
    }

    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return filteredData.count
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "SearchStuff", for: indexPath) as! SearchStuff
        cell.titleLabel.text = filteredData[indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }
    
    func getFilteredData(searchedText: String = String()) {
        let filteredListData: [String] = listData.filter({ (object) -> Bool in
            searchedText.isEmpty ? true : object.lowercased().contains(searchedText.lowercased())
        })
        filteredData = filteredListData
        tableView.reloadData()
    }

}

extension MainTableViewController: UISearchBarDelegate {
    
    func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
        getFilteredData(searchedText: searchBar.text ?? String())
    }
    
    func searchBarSearchButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
        searchBar.endEditing(true)
    }
    
    func searchBarCancelButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
        searchBar.endEditing(true)
        searchBar.text = String()
        getFilteredData()
    }
    
}
```

Output:

[image]

This way you can ignore using the `searching` variable for handling different states of the table view.

Comment: @Tom, You mean you are adding a search bar in the navigation controller? Are you using UITableViewController?

Comment: @Tom, I have updated the answer above please check.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `UINavigationController` , you can easily implement `UISearchController`

```
let searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)

    private func setSearchController() {
    searchController.searchBar.placeholder = "Search".localized
    searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
    searchController.obscuresBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
    searchController.searchBar.delegate = self
    navigationItem.searchController = searchController
    definesPresentationContext = true
}

    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    setSearchController()
}
```

Comment: @Tom You do not need to add the `UISearchBar` at all if you are using `UISearchController` . Maybe this tutorial will make it more clear for you, is is well writen: [Tutorial link](https://www.raywenderlich.com/4363809-uisearchcontroller-tutorial-getting-started)